# infer type from constructor options

Tags: typescript, class, types, type-inference, zod

This works, but I'm sure there's a nicer way of doing this, I'm using zod for schema validation on values i have zero control over from the user.

```
const SchemaValue = z.object({
  translatedValue: z.string().or(z.number())
});

const SchemaInput = z.object({
  truncate: z.number()
});
```

I then have a very simple class, which takes those schemas and performs validation, and also infers the type back to a method passed to the "Action".

```
interface ActionOptions<I, V> {
  name: string;
  inputSchema: z.AnyZodObject;
  valueSchema: z.AnyZodObject;
  validator: (input: I, value: V) => Promise<[string | null, boolean]>;
}

export class Action<I, V> {
  options: ActionOptions<I, V>;
  constructor(options: ActionOptions<I, V>) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  async run(value: V, input: I): Promise<void> {
    // additional code is here to validate value & input against valueSchema and inputSchema
    await this.options.validator(
      input,
      value,
    );
  }
}
```

I then use this like so:

```
const action = new Action<z.infer<typeof InputSchema>, z.infer<typeof ValueSchema>>({
  inputSchema: InputSchema,
  valueSchema: ValueSchema,
  name: 'someAction',
  async validator(input, value) {
    return [null, true];
  }
});
```

This works, intellisense on validator for input & value is correct, however I just can't help but think there's a nicer way of achieving this without having to pass through the types to the constructor, the only reason I'm asking is I'm trying to make the use of `Action` as simple as possible!

I'm wondering if there's a way to infer the types from inputSchema and valueSchema without passing them through the constructor when calling a new instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

`z.AnyZodObject` is not a generic and erases any automatic inference.

#### The solution

Use `z.Schema<T>` to automatically infer the type since it is a generic.

#### Example

```
...
interface ActionOptions<I, V> {
  name: string;
  inputSchema: z.Schema<I>;
  valueSchema: z.Schema<V>;
  validator: (input: I, value: V) => Promise<[string | null, boolean]>;
}
...

const action = new Action({
  inputSchema: InputSchema,
  valueSchema: ValueSchema,
  name: 'someAction',
  async validator(input, value) {
    return [null, true];
  }
});
```

### Edit & Caveat

The above solution works as long as you aren't using more advanced features of `zod` such as `.optional().default(1)`. If you are, here is an alternative that works for the above and the transformative operations.

```
const OptionalValue = z.object({
  translatedValue: z.number().optional().default(1),
});

function validateIncorrect<T>(schema: z.Schema<T>, value: unknown, callback: (validatedValue: T) => void) {
  const validatedValue = schema.parse(value);
  return callback(validatedValue);
}

validateIncorrect(OptionalValue, { translatedValue: 2 }, (v) => {
  // incorrect
  // { translatedValue?: number | undefined; }
  console.log(v); 
});

function validateCorrect<T extends z.AnyZodObject>(schema: T, value: unknown, callback: (validatedValue: z.infer<T>) => void) {
  const validatedValue = schema.parse(value);
  return callback(validatedValue);
}
validateCorrect(OptionalValue, { translatedValue: 2 }, (v) => {
  // correct
  // { translatedValue: number; }
  console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: This seems to be working!

When I simply add `export` before `const action = new Action` it says "implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer." - is there a way around this without having to declare the generics again?

Comment: Ignore me, I was incorrect above! Was my setup that was wrong!